# New object initialization in C#

Tags: c#, object, initialization

I'm new to C# and trying to understand object initialization. My question is can I initialize a new object without any parameters and just with empty curly braces? does that make sense?

For Eg: Classname object = new Classname {};

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Microsoft provides a lot of detailed tutorials and books about c#. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: Classname object = new Classname (); is how you make an object without parameters.

Comment: Thank you Poul Bak

Comment: You could have just tried it to see if the compiler allows it instead of asking us.

Comment: Did you try? The easiest way to find out the answer to a "can I?" question is just to try it.

Comment: I can not run the program. I'm tracing the code and learning, but yeah I will figure out a way to run it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can download a free version.  Or just check msdn.

Comment: You can try it on a free online compiler, such as https://dotnetfiddle.net/. And the answer is, yes, you can use empty curley braces to initialize a class, provided that it has a default constructor (one which requires no arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can initialize an object without any parameters,
let me explain simply,
an object is just a copy from a class, it has a copy of all the public methods and fields inside this class.
We use objects to access members of a class
so let's assume you have two classes X and Y
and you want to be able to use the non-static public members of class X in class Y
then in class Y you can instantiate an object from class X

```
X myObjectName = new X();
```

So what about the constructor part (the parenthesis)
this is just for you to initialize fields defined in class X constructor, in other words you might want to access the public members in class X but you want them to have certain values before you access them, so in class X you should make a constructor, which basically says whatever object instantiated from my class should initialize the following fields, for example in class X you could have this constructor

```
public X (int num) {
this.num = num;
}
```

This basically means that when you instantiate an object from class X you will be required to also pass an integer to initialize field num in class X. Yet you have to know that whatever value you will initialize num with, this value is just a copy that exists in your object but not other objects and not the class itself
for example you can make the following two objects from class X in class Y

```
X object_1 = new X(5);
X object_2 = new X(12);
```

this doesn't mean that you change the value of num field in class X but rather means that you made two objects that are a copy of that class and each copy has a different value of num.
So the reason why you can make an object without initializing any fields, is if you for example want to access the class methods only or maybe you want the default values for the fields. btw you can overload constructors, which means you can multiple constructors that one for example that requires no arguments, so you can use this one when you want to instantiate an object without any parameters, an one that accepts an integer and you use this one when you want to initialize the value of num field when you instantiate the object example

```
public X () {

}
```

and the other is

```
public X(int num) {
this.num = num
}
```

Then in class Y you can make this

```
X object_1 = new X();
X object_2 = new X(15);
```

I hope i gave you a good explanation